# Difference between self.variable and variable

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, accessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between class property mVar and instance variable self.mVar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278389/difference-between-class-property-mvar-and-instance-variable-self-mvar)

I am new to developing in Objective-C and I couldn't quite figure out what the difference is between the following:

First let me explain my situation. I've got an `NSMutableArray`, and I created and outlet for it in my .h file. Now when I assign an array to it as

```
self.myMutableArray=myArray
```

I get an error; However just

```
myMutableArray=myArray
```

works fine.

I am not interested in the resolving of the error. I just want to know what is the difference when putting `self` in front of something? And why I am able to use the variable also without `self` and what restrictions that brings with it?

Comment: Show us the code, especially where your property is declared in the header.

Comment: Note that there’s no such thing as `self.instanceVariable`: it’s either `self->instanceVariable`, `instanceVariable` or `self.declaredProperty`.

Comment: Here is a link that talks about this very topic: [http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1193-calling-self-object-rather-than-calling-the-object-directly-in-objective-c/]

Comment: Which covers @Bavarious's suspicion that this question is about an ivar _without_ a corresponding property.

Comment: Seriously, you couldn't have searched for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.property = value;
```

is equal to:

```
[self setProperty:value];
```

That is to say, the declaration using `self.` goes through the object's accessor method, rather than using direct access.

They have different causes and effects. Perhaps the most notable is that direct access will often leads to reference count issues (leaks/zombies) if not used with care. The accessor is responsible for handling memory management - if synthesised, or if you implement it yourself.

**The General Rule:** You should favor using the accessors (`self.blah = thing;`) over direct access (`blah = thing;`) until you know when and why you would make exceptions to this rule.

**The immediate exception:** There is one exception to the general rule: Do not use the accessors in partially constructed states, such as the object's initializer or `dealloc`. In those cases, use direct access:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (0 != self) {
    things = [NSArray new];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc << not needed with ARC, in this case
{
  [things release], things = 0;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

**Update**

Describing Bavarious' suspicion of the error:

It sounds like you have declared an instance variable, but have *not* declared an associated property or proper accessors (e.g. the setter). Here's a breakdown of a class' declaration with ivars and properties:

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject
{
@private
  NSMutableArray * myMutableArray; << declares an instance variable
}

// the property declaration:
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray * myMutableArray;
// adds the accessors:
//   - (NSMutableArray *)myMutableArray; << getter
//   - (void)setMyMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *)arg; << setter
// to the class' interface.

@end


@implementation MONObject

// @synthesize below generates the accessors for the property
// myMutableArray, using "myMutableArray" ivar by default.
@synthesize myMutableArray;

- (void)zumBeispiel
{
  NSUInteger count = 0;

  // direct access:
  count = [myMutableArray count];
  // is equal to:
  count = [self->myMutableArray count];

  // Access via the getter:
  count = [self.myMutableArray count]; << equal to [self myMutableArray]
  // is equal to:
  count = [[self myMutableArray] count];
}

@end
```

Comment: You might want to write a brief paragraph explaining declared properties vs. instance variables. I have the impression that the OP hasn’t declared properties at all.

Comment: @Bavarious updated - edit away, if you like. cheers

Comment: In your exception you wrote things = [NSArray new]; whereas you state that if assigning a value you should always use self. So why dod you just use things= and not self.things=  ?

Comment: @iJatrat Because you should not use the accessors in `init`. That program demonstrates "The Immediate Exception" to the "General Rule". The exception is that you should avoid using the class' (public) instance methods (including, but not limited to, accessors) in partially constructed states (which `init...` and `dealloc` qualify as). For details as to why this is the exception, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932677/initializing-a-property-dot-notation/5932733#5932733

Comment: @Justin thanks a lot! Cleared up a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

self.variable is a property defined in the .h file like so

```
@property (retain) NSString *variable;
```

and

```
@synthesize variable;
```

in the .m

whereas just "variable" is defined as

```
@interface MyClass: MyParent {
     NSString *varaible;
}
```

in the .h